# How to use compareTo while iterating through an array

Tags: java, arrays, comparable

What is the correct way to use the compareTo inside for loop? I'd like to sort the `Course` objects in ascending order inside the array. I'm worried about the correct syntax for compareTo inside a loop in my `insert()` method.

`if((array[i].courseNumber.compareTo(object.courseNumber)) <= 0)` - is giving me error.

```
public class Courses implements Comparable{
    private String title;
    private int courseNumber;
    private Courses[] array;
    private int size;

    public Courses(String title, int courseNumber){
        this.title = title;
        this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
        this.array = new Courses[10];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void insert(String title, int courseNumber){
        Courses object = new Courses(title, courseNumber);
        if(size == 0){
            array[0] = object;
        }
        else{
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if((array[i].courseNumber.compareTo(object.courseNumber)) <= 0)
                    //do STUFF
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Courses){
            Courses obj1 = (Courses)o;

            return this.courseNumber - obj1.courseNumber;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
if((array[i].courseNumber.compareTo(object.courseNumber)) <= 0)
```

Is giving you an error because `courseNumber` is a primitive (not an object), so there is no `compareTo` method defined on it.

If you would like to use that syntax to compare integers, you can use the static `Integer.compare` method.

```
if(Integer.compare(array[i].courseNumber, object.courseNumber) <= 0)
```

If you want to use your defined `compareTo` method then do

```
if(array[i].compareTo(object) <= 0))
```

Comment: but compare() is a method of Comparator, right? How could I call compareTo() from the loop?

Comment: It is, but `Integer` is the Comparator, not `int`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there any way to call a compareTo() from the loop?

Comment: Yeah, see the edits. The loop doesn't prevent you from calling anything, you just have to call it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Hint : You are not passing the object as parameter.

How does this compare two objects ?

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if((array[i].courseNumber.compareTo(object.courseNumber)) <= 0)
                    //do STUFF
            }
```

You should look at `Arrays.sort(Object[])` which will take care about ordering it using the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: I tried compareTo(new Integer(object.courseNumber)) but still not working.

Comment: compareTo() compares two objects. e1.compareTo(e2) where e1 and e2 are objects, not data members of the objects.

Comment: This code in your answer doesn't compile. If you are going to answer, give an answer, not hints and questions